# Handling race condition at the time of renewing the session

Tags: session-management

> I've recently asked this question on SO. As the question was not answered yet, I've come up with an approach. But I wanted to check if there is not any security flaw in this solution.

**Question**

I had written a session management plugin in node.js for Muneem web framework. Here is pseudo code to create a new session;

```
function createSession(){
    // read encrypted session-id from the request
    if( sessionId ){
      // decrypt it
      if (decryptedSessionId ) {
        //read session detail from the store
        options.store.get(decryptedSessionId, (err, sessionFromStore) => {
          if(err){
            throw Error(err);
          }else if( sessionFromStore){
            if( shouldRenew(sessionFromStore) ){
              //delete previous session
              options.store.destroy(sessionFromStore.id, err=> {
                //update the session object in memory
              });
            }
          }else{ //session detail is not present in store
            // create new session
          }
        }); 
      } else { //invalid or tempered session
        // throw error
      }
    }else{ //session-id is not presnet in request
      // create new session
    }
}
```

As you can notice, I'm renewing a session when it is valid and satisfy certain conditions by deleting the previous session. But I don't update it in the store immediately. Instead, I update the session information in the store and set the cookies when the response is being sent to the client.

Now suppose a condition, when the server receives multiple requests with the same session-id which is eligible to renew. I renew the session on the first request.

*Scenarios*

1. Session is not updated in store. So I'll renew the previous session with another new session id. A user will have multiples session-id in this case.
2. Session is updated in the store. Now, the previous session will not be available in the store. I'll have to ask the user to login again if it is authorized session. Or I'll create another session.

**Solution**

To solve this race condition, I was thinking to create a DB table where the records can self-expired after a fix duration, say transition-time. When a session should be renewed, we do an entry in *expired-session* table with the old and new session id. Rest of the operations are the same as per above pseudo code. Now, if the next request with expired session-id reaches to the server within transition time, say 10 secs, then we'll fetch new session-id and continue the session.

[Here](https://github.com/node-muneem/satr) is the full code, in case we need.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but wouldn't it be easier to just update the session in the store to indicate a new expired time?  That would update cookie too without having to destroy the recreate it. I haven't t used node.js, and I'm mostly a Java/Python guy, so that may not be possible.

Comment: since this is about the concept so language is not the limitation.
I'm already updating new session-id and expiry time when renewing the session. But it'll not handle the race condition. As the next request reaches to the server with previous session id (expired now) before the first request (now with new session id) responded to the client. So you actually don't know if the expired session-id is actually expired or invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this situation will never arise. As I read somewhere, there is no point of securing static files (CSS, img, js) which are used on a web page. Instead, we should authenticate the main route only.